# Is there a way in Visual Studio to check that for each enum defined in a c# project, all values specify their corresponding base type value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums

This is kind of a bizarre question, but it's simply just a matter of checking things efficiently. As the title states, I would like to quickly check that all enums in a particular project have all their base type values specified. So for example, I might have:

```
public enum Animal
{
    Bird = 0,
    Cat = 1,
    Dog = 2
}
```

This enum has its int base type values specified. If it were:

```
public enum Animal
{
    Bird,
    Cat,
    Dog
}
```

then the base values would not have been specified.

Is there a way to either automatically check that this is the case for all enums, or quickly pull up all enums in the project via some Visual Studio search tool or other command and then manually check this is the case? I imagine the former option is not possible, so I guess the question boils down to: how do I pull up all classes with enums in my Visual Studio window?

Comment: By default the first enumeration item has a value of 0.  The second have a value of 1, and so forth.  This is always the default.

Comment: Is there a particular problem that requires you to know if an enum has been explicitly given values rather than implicitly valued (i.e. consecutively starting from 0)?

Comment: I have been told that enums should try to specify their values so that if someone adds a value, the auto ordering doesn't change the other values. So I am just going through and making sure that all the enums specify their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of enforcing this would be to use a code analyzer, such as fx-cop with a custom rule, or a static analyzer on Roslyn.  Both options would require significant effort.

---

As for the 2nd part of your question:

> how do I pull up all classes with enums in my Visual Studio window?

This should get you what you want for your 2nd option (with a slight change of a false positive).

From the main menu: Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files

- Find what: " enum " (notice the spaces)
- Look in: Entire Solution.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll probably pass on the first part. And thanks for the second part -- that works fine.